# Laravel HttpException - No error message

Tags: laravel

I'm not able to get a descriptive error message for an ajax request hitting my application.  I don't see a problem with how this is setup.  I've tried removing the controller method altogether and this is still failing before it ever touches the controller.

**My route:**

```
+--------+----------+------------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                    | Name  | Action                                                       | Middleware                      |
+--------+----------+------------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|        | POST     | subscribe              |       | App\Http\Controllers\SubscriptionController@create           | web,auth                        |
+--------+----------+------------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

in web.php:

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'auth',
], function () {
    Route::post('subscribe', 'SubscriptionController@create');
    Route::post('unsubscribe', 'SubscriptionController@delete');
});
```

**My VueJS:**

```
this.$http.post('/subscribe', {
    my-data: 'values'
}).then(response => {
    // success
}, response => {
    console.error('Failed to subscribe');
});
```

**The response:**

[image]

```
{
    "message": "",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException",
    "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php",
    "line": 203,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php",
            "line": 175,
            "function": "prepareException",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/app/Exceptions/Handler.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "render",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 83,
            "function": "render",
            "class": "App\\Exceptions\\Handler",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 55,
            "function": "handleException",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php",
            "line": 49,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php",
            "line": 63,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php",
            "line": 37,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php",
            "line": 59,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 102,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 647,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 622,
            "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 588,
            "function": "runRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 577,
            "function": "dispatchToRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 176,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 30,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php",
            "line": 56,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 30,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 30,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php",
            "line": 27,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php",
            "line": 46,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 102,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 151,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 116,
            "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/public/index.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you show code of SubscriptionController?

Comment: @wanghanlin I could, but it doesn't matter since I can remove that class altogether and still get the same error.

Comment: I think you should write this route in the api section because in the web there is a `CSRF` verification that's why you have 419 status code as a response !

Comment: That makes sense... I thought VueJS was bootstrapped to handle the CSRF out of the gate.  If it's an ajax request for my own site, I don't really want auth, I'd prefer to use CSRF as a form of security rather than locking down the endpoints by api key.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the web section (`web.php` routes file) there is a `CSRF` verification with the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware as the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf#csrf-introduction) sais :

> The VerifyCsrfToken middleware, which is included in the web
>   middleware group, will automatically verify that the token in the
>   request input matches the token stored in the session.

That's why you have 419 status code as a response.

And in the API section (`api.php` routes file), witch  is dedicated to 'stateless' API calls, there is no `CSRF` verification, but you should use an API authentification via `JWT` or `Laravel Passport` for example.

So if you want to use the web section you should add `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header for your ajax calls with the value of the generated `csrf_token` that you can get it from the meta tag for example like this :

```
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
```

Then use `$.ajaxSetup` before ajax call:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: "/subscribe",
    // ....
})
```

Comment: Thinking about this more - an ajax request wouldn't break CSRF though would it?

Comment: Thanks. This helped me. A couple of suggestions. 
 1) https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/ says, "Its use is not recommended," because of the global impact on other libraries. I used "beforeSend" to set the header in my ajax call instead.  2) I had to change "_token" to "csrf-token". (I'm a laravel newbie though, so I don't know if that's unique to my environment or version.)