# Laravel ajax Delete request - unknow status

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5, http-delete

Hi i cant figure out why my ajax call does return Unknow status error (419), because ajax call looks good also route name is good and Card import is added also =\

{{}} is here cause its inside Blade engine

here is my AJAX call

```
       $.ajax({
            type: "delete",
            url: "{{route("cart.destroy", $cartitemjs->rowId)}}",
            success: function () {
                console.log("Produkt bol vymazani");
            }
        })
```

and there is my destroy mehod inside a controller

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    Cart::remove($id);
}
```

> DELETE    | cart/{cart}                    | cart.destroy     | App\Http\Controllers\CartController@destroy                            | web

Comment: Have you tried to modify destroy method such that it returns true/false? For this, just add return keyword before Cart::remove($id);

Comment: @BahriddinAbdiev yup and still Unknow =\

Comment: Try my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46450808/4881811) !! you must add the csrf_token :)

Comment: Where did you define the route: in api.php or web.php?

Comment: web because i wanted avoid using token

Comment: I think it is because you forgot to include csrf_field, didn't you?

Comment: but its there diffrent between get / delete type ? cause get type work perfect when i adding item into card using ajax without CSRF

Comment: but delete type is actually POST with hidden type field with "DELETE" value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to use the web section you should add `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header for your ajax calls with the value of the generated `csrf_token` that you can get it from the meta tag for example like this :

```
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
```

Then use `$.ajaxSetup` before ajax call:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type: "delete",
    // ....
})
```

Comment: perfect its worket thank you and Bahriddin Abdiev, i font  figure out DELETE its like POST :)