# Laravel Resource API CURL | store/delete don't work

Tags: laravel, rest, api, postman

I'm trying to create my own resource API in Laravel, I test the api via Postman program, index() and show() functions (with GET requests) work well, but unfortunatelly store()/delete() functions dont't work (POST, PUT, DELETE requests).

I've tried a lot of tutorials, and result the same, I can't use POST, PUT, DELETE requests (or can't test them properly via Postman)

More details:

1. I have DB with tables (with relations): Categories, Startups, Contacts, Countries

```
       1.1 One Category can have many Startups 
       1.2 One Contact can have many Startups  
       1.3 One Country can have many Contacts
```

2. I defined Api Routes in web.php (not in api.php), (I'm trying to make api for Startups Table):

   ```
       // get list startups
       Route::get('api/startups', 'Admin\StartupController@index');
       // get single startup
       Route::get('api/startup/{id}', 'Admin\StartupController@show');
       // create new startup
       Route::post('api/startup', 'Admin\StartupController@store');
       // update startup
       Route::put('api/startup', 'Admin\StartupController@store');
       // delete startup
       Route::delete('api/startup/{id}', 'Admin\StartupController@destroy');
   ```
3. Controller code (StartupController), I'm showing only one method - store() 
   (I think it's enough for identifying the issue)

   ```
   public function store(Request $request) {

   $startup = Startup::create([
       'category_id' => $request->category()->id,
       'contact_id' => $request->contact()->id,
       'name' => $request->name,
       'description' => $request->description,
       'url' => $request->url,
       'logo' => $request->logo,
   ]);

   return new StartupResource($startup);
   ```

   Also second option of the function (which doesn't work too):

   ```
   public function store(Request $request) {
     $startup = $request->isMethod('put') ? Startup::findOrFail($request->startup_id) : new Startup;

     $startup->id = $request->input('startup_id');
     $startup->name = $request->input('startup_name');
     $startup->description = $request->input('startup_description');
     $startup->url = $request->input('startup_url');
     $startup->logo = $request->input('startup_logo');

     if ($startup->save()) {
        return new StartupResource($startup);
     }
   }
   ```
4. My migration

   ```
    Schema::create('startups', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->increments('id');
       $table->integer('category_id');
       $table->integer('contact_id')->nullable();
       $table->string('name');
       $table->mediumText('description');
       $table->string('url');
       $table->boolean('public')->default(false);
       $table->string('logo');
       $table->timestamps();
   });
   ```
5. toArray() function in resources

   ```
   public function toArray($request) {
      return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'description' => $this->description,
        'url' => $this->url,
        'public' => $this->public,
        'logo' => $this->logo,
        'created_at' => (string) $this->created_at,
        'updated_at' => (string) $this->updated_at,
        'category' => $this->category,
        'contact' => $this->contact
      ];
   }
   ```
6. (Additional) may be it will help - how I test it in Postman

   [row (submitting json)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hd1WI.png)

   [form-data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DZLx.png)

Comment: if you dd() or var_dump the data sent to your method what do you get? is it empty?

Comment: hm, sorry but I just have Postman for submitting POST/PUT/DELETE requests, how can I use dd() ?

Comment: for example you could return the value of one of the parameters you are expecting or $request->all() to see what you are sending. So the idea is to see if the data you are sending is getting to your method, at least that would be one of the first things I would test.

Comment: oh, yes I tried this (return $request->all();) - It returns the same error , even when I return 1; 
it throw the same error

Comment: ok, sorry I had not seen your links, this may be your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46449768/laravel-httpexception-no-error-message/46450808

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a CSRF protection.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf

api.php routes don't have this protection(only web.php).
So, you should decide - use api routes, or just use VerifyCsrfToken::$except property to avoid this protection for some routes.